# How to code nonlinear constraints in CPlex opl?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, nonlinear-optimization, check-constraints, opl

This is a part of my Cplex code. I want to code the constraint below but it seems nonlinear constraints and can not run in CPlex opl. Can anyone help me deal with it?
[Here is the constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1PzC.png)

...

```
int Z_val = ...;
int T_val = 10;
int I_val = ...;
int J_val = ...;
float alpha = ...; // The average loading rate of delivery trucks;
range Z = 1 .. Z_val;// Number of vessels
range T = 1 .. T_val; // Number of time intervals
range I = 1 .. I_val; // Number of gate lanes
range J = 1 .. J_val; // Number of yard blocks

float beta_zj[Z][J] = ...;

// Define sets
{int} Z_j[J];

// Objective function or constraints go here

execute {
  // Iterate over j and z to update Z sets
  for (var j in J) {
    for (var z in Z) {
      if (beta_zj[z][j] > 0) {
        Z_j[j].add(z); // Add z to the set Z_j[j]
      }
    }
  }

  // Print the result (optional)
  for (var j in J) {
    writeln("Z_j[", j, "] = ", Z_j[j]);
  }
}

// Derived variables
dvar int+ lambda_zt_g[Z][T];// Number of trucks related to vessel z arriving at terminal gate at interval t
dvar int+ lambda_it_g[I][T];// Number of trucks arriving at gate lane i at interval t
dvar int+ lambda_t_y[T];// Number of export containers arriving at yard at interval t
dvar int+ lambda_jt_y[J][T];// Number of export containers arriving at block j at interval t
…..
….
subject to 
{

    forall ( j in J, t in T ){//(15)
    
    lambda_jt_y[j][t] == lambda_t_y[t] * alpha * sum ( z in Z_j[j] )
       (beta_zj[z][j] * lambda_zt_g[z][t] / sum ( i in I ) lambda_it_g[i][t]);
 }
```

code nonlinear constraints

Answer (score 0):

Since all your decision variables are integer you could use constraint programming in CPLEX.

The following model works:

```
using CP;

int Z_val = 10;
int T_val = 10;
int I_val = 10;
int J_val = 2;
float alpha = 0.5; // The average loading rate of delivery trucks;
range Z = 1 .. Z_val;// Number of vessels
range T = 1 .. T_val; // Number of time intervals
range I = 1 .. I_val; // Number of gate lanes
range J = 1 .. J_val; // Number of yard blocks

float beta_zj[i in Z][j in J] = i*j;

// Define sets
{int} Z_j[J];

// Objective function or constraints go here

execute {
  // Iterate over j and z to update Z sets
  for (var j in J) {
    for (var z in Z) {
      if (beta_zj[z][j] > 0) {
        Z_j[j].add(z); // Add z to the set Z_j[j]
      }
    }
  }

  // Print the result (optional)
  for (var j in J) {
    writeln("Z_j[", j, "] = ", Z_j[j]);
  }
}

// Derived variables
dvar int+ lambda_zt_g[Z][T];// Number of trucks related to vessel z arriving at terminal gate at interval t
dvar int+ lambda_it_g[I][T];// Number of trucks arriving at gate lane i at interval t
dvar int+ lambda_t_y[T];// Number of export containers arriving at yard at interval t
dvar int+ lambda_jt_y[J][T];// Number of export containers arriving at block j at interval t
subject to 
{

    forall ( j in J, t in T ){//(15)
    
    lambda_jt_y[j][t] == lambda_t_y[t] * alpha * sum ( z in Z_j[j] )
       (beta_zj[z][j] * lambda_zt_g[z][t]/ sum ( i in I ) lambda_it_g[i][t]);
     }
   }
```

Comment: This is just a part of my code. How about in the case where there are both integer and float decision variables?

Comment: You can either turn float into decimal as in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodecimalcpo.mod or linearize your non linear constraints . Example https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/multiplybinarybydecisionvariable.mod

Comment: I try to turn float into decimal as in the link but it has Solver error: Problem size limit exceeded. CP Optimizer Community Edition solves problems with search spaces up to 2^1000

Comment: I see your example on linearizing the non linear constraints, however in the example it is for the case of multiplying binary to dvar , how about the more complicated constraints I have mentioned :"lambda_jt_y[j][t] == lambda_t_y[t] * alpha * sum ( z in Z_j[j] )
       (beta_zj[z][j] * lambda_zt_g[z][t]/ sum ( i in I ) lambda_it_g[i][t])"

Comment: You get "CP Optimizer Community Edition solves problems with search spaces up to 2^1000" because you use the free Community edition. If you are in academia you could use the free non limited academic version. For product linearization, you can check https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/multiplyintegerdecisionvariablebydecisionvariable.mod

Comment: I code  it again but CPlex run with no solution and I do not know how  to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77658611/cplex-cp-optimizer-took-forever-to-run-with-no-solution